# Unit testing angular directive with link function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

My link function of a directive

1. shows some dummy mock
2. ask for external data (promise).
3. Whenever the promise resolves or rejectes dummy data is hidden

Is there a way to unit test directive, checking that the dummy data is presented namely is it possible to

1. compile directive
2. do not resolve promises

as both $apply and $digest are resolving the promise and in unit test i am either before compilation or after compilation and promise resolving.